# 1.toString() SyntaxError in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Why the first line below gives error although the second and third lines work fine?

```
1.toString(); // SyntaxError
(1).toString(); // OK
1['toString'](); // OK
```

Comment: And "they" want to make javascript strictly typed!

Comment: Don't worry about him. The specification authors are making it strictly typed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The parser is trying to treat `1.` as the start of a floating-point literal -- only `toString` turns it into an invalid number.

Compare with:

```
1.0.toString()
```

Answer (score 12):

The `.` presents ambiguity. Is it a decimal, or a property accessor?

The interpreter sees it as a decimal, so you can use `..` to allow both the decimal, then the property syntax.

```
1..toString();
```

Or use one of the other ways you show to resolve the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

In `(1).toString()`, (1) forces it to evaluate before .toString() so it works.
In `1.toString()`, 1 is not a valid identifier so it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, using the dot (`.`) can be interpreted in one of two ways:

1. As a [Property Accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) (e.g., `var prop = myObject.prop;`).
2. As part of a [Floating-point Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Floating-point_literals) (e.g. `var num = 1.5;`).

In the above case, the leading `1.` in `1.toString()` is interpreted as a floating point number, hence the error:

> SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal ([learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Identifier_after_number?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default))

This is the same error you get if you try and declare a variable that starts with a number: `var 1person = 'john';`

To prevent the interpreter from seeing the `1.` as a decimal and instead see it as accessing a property on our literal `1`, there are several ways to accomplish this:

```js
// Via white-space after the numeric literal
1 .toString();

1
.toString();

// Via a grouping-operator, aka, parentheses
// @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Grouping_operator
(1).toString();

// Via an additional dot. Made clearer with parentheses as `(1.).toString()`
1..toString();

// Via an explicit fractional part (because `1. === 1.0`)
1.0.toString();

// Via bracket notation
1['toString']();
1.['toString']();
1.0['toString']();
```